# connect to aws using boto - credentials error

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto

Im trying to connect to aws using boto but Im having an error.

First, I created an aws account and then in managment console I clicked in IAM and I created a new user.

This user have associated a AWS_ACESS_KEY_ID and a AWS_SECRET_ACESS_KEY.

And then I stored this user credentials in /etc/boto.cfg and in ~/.boto, like this:

```
[Credentials]
aws_acess_key_id = ...
aws_secret_acess_key = ...
```

Now Im trying to connect to boto but Im having this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "send.py", line 12, in <module>
    s3 = boto.connect_s3()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto-2.36.0-py2.7.egg/boto/__init__.py", line 141, in connect_s3
    return S3Connection(aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto-2.36.0-py2.7.egg/boto/s3/connection.py", line 190, in __init__
    validate_certs=validate_certs, profile_name=profile_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto-2.36.0-py2.7.egg/boto/connection.py", line 569, in __init__
    host, config, self.provider, self._required_auth_capability())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto-2.36.0-py2.7.egg/boto/auth.py", line 985, in get_auth_handler
    'Check your credentials' % (len(names), str(names)))
boto.exception.NoAuthHandlerFound: No handler was ready to authenticate. 1 handlers were checked. ['HmacAuthV1Handler'] Check your credentials

boto [DEBUG]:Retrieving credentials from metadata server.
[ERROR]:Caught exception reading instance data
```

Do you see what can be wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This is because boto cannot find credentials to use.

Make sure `boto.cfg` file is correct, check for spelling as well and still there is problem follow the [Troubleshooting Connections Problem](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting_started.html#troubleshooting-connections)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I follow that boto documentation, and I update my question with the way Im storing credentials that I follow by documentation!

Comment: You have misspelled ``Credentials`` in the example above.  If that is the way it is spelled in your boto config file, that would cause this problem.

Comment: Thanks for notice that. I update the question with that correction!

Comment: also misspelled every usage of `acess`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I corrected the writing errors and now its working ok, thank you!

Comment: Where is `boto.cfg` supposed to be? Not any such file on my system although I have installed `boto`